# Smoothing out jagged mesh edge in edit mode

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

I have a mesh with some jagged edges that need smoothing out without having to do a lot of manual work. It's a zig-zagging mesh and I'm trying to fill out the creases so that there is a somewhat continuous outer edge. The image below is a screenshot of the mesh, with the red line marking where the mesh should follow.

[image: mesh in question]

In other words, I'd want to fill in those jagged creases with edges like so:

[image: Fill in face]

Searching around, most solutions are for making blocking meshes look smooth via shaders, but what I'm trying to do is a little more crude.

One question closer to mine had a pretty good solution: [How do you make a jagged circle edge smooth?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196058/how-do-you-make-a-jagged-circle-edge-smooth)
Here @ChristopherBennett suggested using `Loop Tools`.

Gave that a shot but it doesn't look like it works very well. It misses some of the inner vertices, even when I delete the faces underneath (because I thought it was maybe confusing the tool)

[image: Issue with LoopTools]

Was thinking about smoothing out the outer edge and then lofting the top and bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, You could select chunks of your mesh in Edit Mode, and invoke (Header Menu) *> Mesh > Convex Hull*, followed by <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve*:

[image]

But you lose some edges.

One other possible approach, if you need to retopologise, or *Convex Hull* is not a good starting-point:  somehow make parts of the mesh available to the shipped add-on *Loop Tools*, and its *Curve* operator. (Much Slower)

In Edit mode, duplicate off a region with a profile of interest:

[image]

and..

[image]

- <kbd>F</kbd> fill, or <kbd>X</kbd> > Limited dissolve, convert it to a single non-planar Ngon
- To make it available to *Loop Tools > Curve*, at least, extrude it. This one is inset, too. Select the projecting vertices. A good sign of acceptable topology is that this can be achieved by selecting the first two vertices, and the rest, incrementally, by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad +</kbd>
- Invoke *Loop Tools > Curve* on that loop.
- Duplicate the loop, or delete the other vertices.

[image]

Now, with Snap set to 'To: Vertex' and 'With: Active', snap the fixed profile back on to the original model. Repeat the process with other profiles.

Then you can (Edge Menu) > *Bridge Edge Loops* reproduce the shapes with better topology.